# About designing a course system. When should I inspect assignments due or not? Where should I put this logic?

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns

I am working on designing a system for students, teachers, etc. to use, and I'm using **Laravel Framework** to develop. Teachers can create course and assign homework to the courses' students, and they can **set the due date for them separately**.

My question is:

1. **When should I check the date is expired or not**?
2. **Where should I put this logic?**

In my opinion:

1. For example, we have course Mathematics for student Aaron, and the teacher is Josh.
   When Aaron or Josh **log into** the system, check their course Mathematics is expired or not. Otherwise, only check when they click on the assignment or course page.
2. Create a middleware for checking, and apply it to Route.

   ```
   Route::group(['middleware' => 'check'], function(){
       Route::get('/dashboard'); 
       Route::get('/courses');
       Route::get('/assignments');
   }
   ```

   Otherwise, create a service(use service and repository design pattern) for controller to call.

   ```
   //controller 
   public function getDashboard(){
       $user = Auth::user();
       ...
       $this->assignmentService->check(); //check for assignment
       $this->courseService->check(); // check for course
       ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say your second implementation is the way to go here. Assignment expire dates are domain logic, which should be checked by a domain service. Middleware feels like something which should be used for infrastructure-level logic, not domain logic.

As a bonus the domain service can be unit-tested better than a middleware.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think now I need to understand the difference of domain service and application service first.

Comment: In short a domain service does things related to your the specific problem your application solves. So if your domain is selling insurances, then calculating the price for a specific insurance is domain logic. Application services are there to facilitate the domain and usually overlap between projects. Lets say you create a middleware which only allows admin pages to be loaded from a specific IP. That middleware could be used in a project regardless of the domain logic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it's really helpful. I've finished developing this function in Application Service today :).

Comment: That's nice to hear. Glad to be of help